# R merge two lists of data frame by position

Tags: r, list, dataframe, merge, position

***1) Correct merging two listst of data.frame:***
I would like to merge two lists of data frame by some common variable (in every data frame) by position (the first data frame from one list with the first dataframe of the other list, the second with the second... the 53rd with the 53rd).
e.g. of lists
input

```
    [[1]]$`16-09-26`
  total price qnty     code     date   REFERENCE
  1011   51.9  17.3    3    45917 16-09-26 RefProd0168
  1012 118.44  4.23   28    42442 16-09-26 RefProd0103
  1013  21.28  5.32    4 14758353 16-09-26 RefProd0263
  1014  10.64  5.32    2 14758360 16-09-26 RefProd0102
  1023  68.16  4.26   16  4127329 16-09-26 RefProd0145
```

str(inputbydate)
List of 2

```
$       :List of 54
..$ 15-08-03:'data.frame':  14 obs. of  6 variables:
.. ..$ total    : Factor w/ 137 levels "","/","101.52",..: 80 117 20 
.. ..$ price    : Factor w/ 49 levels "","10.16","10.38",..: 48 26 29 29 
.. ..$ qnty     : num [1:14] 4 16 3 2 6 4 12 4 16 3 ...
.. ..$ code     : Factor w/ 54 levels "","14458956",..: 21 38 5 6 8 27 28 
.. ..$ date     : Date[1:14], format: "15-08-03" "15-08-03" "15-08-03" ...
.. ..$ REFERENCE: Factor w/ 50 levels "","REFERENCE",..: 9 6 19 5 15 21 8
```

(...)

dput inputbydate e.g.

```
      Names = c("total", "price", "qnty", "code", "date", "REFERENCE"), row.names = c(741L, 742L, 743L, 748L, 750L), class = "data.frame"), `16-05-30` = structure(list(total = structure(c(75L, 3L, 64L, 39L, 95L), .Label =c("","/", "101.52", "105.57",..., "price"), class = "factor")qnty = c(3, 24, 6, 4, 12), code = structure(c(22L, 38L, 5L, 6L, 28L), .Label = c("", "14458956", "code"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(-713534, -713534, -713534, -713534, -713534), class = "Date"), REFERENCE = structure(c(30L, 6L, 19L, 5L, 8L), .Label = c("", "REFERENCE", "RefProd0064", "RefProd0088",...,, class = "factor"))
```

**the second list**

```
   $purchase52
       V9 V12
1 RefProd0103  10
2 RefProd0145   4 
3 RefProd0152   5
4 RefProd0224   2
5 RefProd0642   1

$purchase53
           V9 V12
1 RefProd0102   4
2 RefProd0103  11
3 RefProd0145   9
4 RefProd0152   3
5 RefProd0224   2
6 RefProd0263   5
7 RefProd0642   7

    purchase38:'data.frame':    6 obs. of  2 variables:
    ..$ V9 : Factor w/ 1430 levels "","RefProd","RefProd0001",..: 104 105 147 154 226 265
    ..$ V12: num [1:6] 2 16 8 4 5 2
      $ purchase39:'data.frame':    7 obs. of  2 variables:
    ..$ V9 : Factor w/ 1430 levels "","RefProd","RefProd0001",..: 104 105     147 154 226 265 644
    ..$ V12: num [1:7] 1 20 8 6 1.27 5 1
```

e.g. dput purchase

```
  Names = c("V9", "V12"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("purchase01","purchase02", "purchase03",...,"purchase54"))
```

**I must Merge the list by "references" = "V9"**. REFERENCES from the inputbydate list and V9 vrom the purchase list.

2)**The difference problem**, how to make calculation in each data frame independently.Than after, I have to make a new column with the "qnty" "V12" difference.

**3)Biuld a dinamic table**:Finally, take this value by date (data frame) and make one complete table with all RefProd values at the first column and the differences month by month.

I tried to use

```
llply(inputbydate,function(x){do.call(as.data.frame, lapply(inputbydate, "[[",1)),x=})

mapply(merge, inputbydate,purchase,by.x="REFERENCE", by.y = "V9", SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

do.call, join, merge_all...

It seems that the input list is a list of a list of data frame. Maybe it is making me problems... if I can extract the list inside de list, maybe it is gonna help me.

Any help will be of great value

Comment: If both lists are of same length and corresponding elements are to be merged, could you try this `lapply(1:length(inputbydate),function(x) merge(inputbydate[[x]],purchase[[x]],by.x="REFERENCE", by.y = "V9", SIMPLIFY = FALSE) )` and I would suggest breaking down your problem into simple steps 1) getting correct merge table 2) create new columns 3) arrangement of table

Comment: Please provide reproducible input .  For each list display in your question the output of dput(L).  Cut the lists down (do not cut down the output) if they are large.  See [mcve].

Comment: There seems to be two questions here. The top asks for merge by position but bottom is asking for additional data wrangling with unknown columns (*reference* and *V9* do not show in above) and objects (*inputbydate*, *purchase*). Please edit for clarity.

Comment: Unfortunetlly the lists are not of the same length:
the lapply returns me:
 Error in data.frame(`15-08-03` = list(total = c(80L, 117L, 20L, 5L, 93L,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 14, 8, 6, 4, 5, 7, 10, 9, 11, 3